# Can't get past login screen

Tags: release-juno

Whenever I submit the correct password, my PC does a strange mini-boot (it shows the Dell logo) and then I get straight back to the same login screen, I cannot progress further.
I have never had this issue before and have been using EOS daily for months.

I was using it normally before, but noticed my hard drive was full, so I began deleting some files from my downloads and from the cache for apps I'm no longer using. I'm fairly sure I didn't delete anything vital. I then cleared the recycling bin.
After this it still said there were 0 bytes free, so I restarted my PC where I then encountered this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by removing old files and folders. After that I was able to login normally.